# Is mandatory to use Desfire for encryption?

Tags: nfc, smartcard, iso, mifare, apdu

I'm new to the NFC standards and I have only played with Ntag203, Mifare Classic and Desfire. I'm trying to figure out what is the advantage of Desfire for our application.

I have looked through ISO 14443 and ISO 7816-4 standards and I can only figure out that the Desfire provides a **standards compliant API** to manage encryption to ensure interoperability between OEM client applications, readers and cards.

Let's say I am building a mobile client that needs to encrypt and store data using the same scheme as Desfire (AES or 3DES) - can I do that completely client side with , say ntag203, and not violate any security standards.

I have worked with PCI-DSS and am worried if this is some kind of mandatory technology to be able to process sensitive data like health records, payment balance, etc

Comment: This is not a programming question and it requires too much knowledge about the use case to be answered in any meaningful way

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming.

Comment: This question is definitely about programming - if you check other questions in the same tags, there have been many questions on structure of protocols on smart cards. My question is not about "my" usecase, but any usecase: I understand PCI-DSS, but I dont understand why does one need to spend on a particular set of hardware for NFC. I can use standards compliant client-side software, so what is on-chip security API getting me ?

Comment: I'm not sure, what you are trying to do, giving so different chips. You can always do the encryption manually and transfer the result, but this seems clumsy. What do you want to achieve: integrity, confidentiality or both? And for which amount of data? Stay away from Mifare Classic if you have no legacy application requiring it. Health Care and payment cards typically use *real* smart cards for good reason.